# Apache2 is not working... (warning)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, debian

So i'm trying to deploy a rails 4.2.5 app, and at the last step of it, while apache2 needs to be reloaded, it fails, and I don't have many informations about this.

I browsed the web, but there isn't many answers about this, so i don't know what to do...

```
Active: active (exited) (Result: exit-code) since dim. 2016-01-31 03:01:31 CET; 9min ago
Process: 10766 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 10993 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 10773 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

janv. 31 03:08:47 vps240378.ovh.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
janv. 31 03:08:47 vps240378.ovh.net systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: Apache2 web server.
janv. 31 03:10:52 vps240378.ovh.net apache2[10945]: Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
janv. 31 03:10:52 vps240378.ovh.net apache2[10945]: Apache2 is not running ... (warning).
janv. 31 03:10:52 vps240378.ovh.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
janv. 31 03:10:52 vps240378.ovh.net systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: Apache2 web server.
janv. 31 03:11:23 vps240378.ovh.net apache2[10993]: Reloading web server: apache2 failed!
janv. 31 03:11:23 vps240378.ovh.net apache2[10993]: Apache2 is not running ... (warning).
janv. 31 03:11:23 vps240378.ovh.net systemd[1]: apache2.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
janv. 31 03:11:23 vps240378.ovh.net systemd[1]: Reload failed for LSB: Apache2 web server.
```

Does anybody know how to deal with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your top three lines you look like you are stopping apache, trying to reload,  which falls - because it's stopped.  And them starting it again.  Is that the issue?  If so don't stop apache,  just reload.  Reload is there so you don't have to restart.

Apologies if this is not the issue just my first take.

Reload provides instructions to children to complete their current request and stop,  while new requests are served by your new configuration. If apache is stopped,  there's nothing to do.

Comment: I tried to start apache2 then reload it, but it had the same error, maybe there is an error somewhere but i don't where i can find this information

Comment: OK, if starting is working, and reload is not then why not post up the restart section of /etc/init.d/apache2 - that's what's giving the error. The other thing is to have a look at is the apache error.log - depends on where it lives but could be /var/log/httpd/error_log